# CDO - Not Sending email

Tags: asp-classic, cdo.message, cdonts

Helllo,
i am calling ASP page from HTML on click of submit button, and in ASP i want to send Email.
So i have writen below code, but neither it is sending mail nor i am getting any Error.

```
<%
dim myMail
Set myMail=CreateObject("CDO.Message")
myMail.Subject="Sending email with CDO"
myMail.From="FromEmail"
myMail.To="ToEmail"

myMail.HTMLBody = "<h1>This is a message.</h1>"
On Error Resume Next
myMail.Send
If Err.Number = 0 then
  Response.ContentType="application/json"
  Response.Write "{ request: 'success'}"
Else
  Response.ContentType="application/json"
  Response.Write "{ request: 'failed'}"
End If

set myMail=nothing
%>
```

Can anyone please help me on this..?

Comment: Are you using a valid email address to send your mails?

Answer (score 0):

This code also includes RegExp to prevent your email form from being used by spammers.

```
<%
strVisitorMSG= _
"Your message goes here" & _
"If it's a long message you can break it up using & _" & _
"The last line of your meassage omits & _"

Set RegularExpressionObject = New RegExp
With RegularExpressionObject
.Pattern = "^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$"
.IgnoreCase = True
.Global = True
End With
expressionmatch = RegularExpressionObject.Test(Request.Form("E-mail"))

If expressionmatch  Then

Dim ObjSendMail
Set ObjSendMail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 '1 'Send the message using the network (SMTP over the network).
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "Your.smtpServer.name" ' this is your smtp server usually something like smtp.somedomain.com
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25 '25 is the standard smtp port but check with your host to be sure
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = False 'Use SSL for the connection (True or False)
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 0 'Can be 0 for No Authentication, 1 for basic authentication or 2 for NTLM (check with your host)
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "Username" 'The username log in credentials for the email account sending this email, not needed if authentication is set to 0
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "emailPassword" 'The password log in credentials for the email account sending this email, not needed if authentication is set to 0

ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Update

ObjSendMail.From = "FromEmail"
ObjSendMail.To = "ToEmail"
ObjSendMail.Subject = "Place your subject here"

ObjSendMail.TextBody = strVisitorMSG 'uncomment to send plain text email
'ObjSendMail.HTMLBody = strVisitorMSG 'uncomment to send html formatted email

ObjSendMail.Send

Set ObjSendMail = Nothing

End If
Set RegularExpressionObject = nothing
%>
```

The configuration fields have been commented for your convenience.  If your web host mail server does not require authentication you can omit the last three Configuration fields (authentication, username & password).

In this line 'expressionmatch = RegularExpressionObject.Test(Request.Form("E-mail"))' the word "E-mail" is the name of the form field containing the sender's email address.

Answer (score 0):

You are continuing on an error so you wont see an error even if get one.

Remove

```
On Error Resume Next
```

from your code and see what error message you get.